# Date saving issue when published in local IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, date, iis

I am saving a date to the database which is initially in **dd/mm/yy** format. I have converted it into **yyyy-MM-dd** format by using this code

```
 public static string ChangeDateFormatToDataBaseStyle(this string strDateTime)
 {                
   DateTime objDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateTime);
   return objDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 }
```

The date is saved when i am running the code in visual studio. But it does not work when it 
runs on IIS.

Can anybody help me out with this problem?

Comment: Please define "does not work"

Comment: What's the field type in your database? If it *isn't* a date/time type, why isn't it? And if it *is* a date/time type, then it really isn't in a format in the database at all. And "it does not work" doesn't tell us anything about what actually happens...

Comment: The field type is smalldatetime. When the Save button is clicked a message should be displayed on a Label either  telling 'Saved' or 'Error saving data'. But nothing is displayed.

Comment: You don't have to convert to the "database" format. Convert it once, in your code, to a `DateTime`. Then pass that value across to the database in a parameter, and let ADO.Net deal with any necessary conversions to produce a `smalldatetime` directly in the database.